# How to retry only failed tests in the CI job run on Gitlab?

Tags: continuous-integration, automated-tests, gitlab-ci

Our automation tests run in gitlab CI environment. We have a regression suite of around 80 tests.
If a test fails due to some intermittent issue, the CI job fails and since the next stage is dependent on the Regression one, the pipeline gets blocked.
We retry the job to rerun regression suite expecting this time it will pass, but some other test fails this time.
So, my question is:
*Is there any capability using which on retrying the failed CI job, only the failed tests run (Not the whole suite)?*

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `retry` keyword when you specify the parameters for a job, to define how many times the job can be automatically retried: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#configuration-parameters

Comment: Hi Kim. First of all, thanks for answering. I went through the link you shared and although retry have good amount of capabilities, but my use case is something different. I want the retry to be done only on the failed tests, not on the whole job.
However, I am not confident whether it can be handled on the CI level.

Answer (score 1):

If you use pytest, you can do something like this:

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: example_image
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - pytest --alluredir=./reports
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - .pytest_cache/v/cache/lastfailed

rerun_failed:
  stage: rerun-failed
  image: example_image
  script:
    - if [ -e ".pytest_cache/v/cache/lastfailed" ]; then pytest --lf --alluredir=./reports; else echo "No failed tests"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Retry Only Failed Scenarios]**

Yes, but it depends.  let me explain.  I'll mention the psuedo-steps which can be performed to retry only failed scenarios. The steps are specific to pytest, but can be modified depending on the test-runner.

1. Execute the test scenarios with `--last-failed`. At first, all 80 scenarios will be executed.
2. The test-runner creates a metadata file containing a list of failed tests. for example, pytest creates a folder `.pytest_cache` containing `lastfailed` file with the list of failed scenarios.
3. We now have to add the `.pytest_cache` folder in the GitLab cache with the `key=<gitlab-pipeline-id>`.
4. User checks that there are 5 failures and reruns the failed job.
5. When the job is retried it will see that now `.pytest_cache` folder exists in the GitLab cache and will copy the folder to your test-running directory. (shouldn't fail if the cache doesn't exist to handle the 1st execution)
6. you execute the same test cases with the same parameter `--last-failed`  to execute the tests which were failed earlier.
7. In the rerun, 5 test cases will be executed.

Assumptions:

1. The test runner you are using creates a metadata file like pytest.

POC Required:

- I have not done POC for this but in theory, it looks possible. The only doubt I have is how Gitlab parses the results. Ideally in the final result, all 80 scenarios should be `pass`.  If it doesn't work out this way, then we have to have 2 jobs. `execute tests` -> `[manual] execute failed tests` to get 2 parsed results.  I am sure with 2 stages, it will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Retry Analyser. This will help you definitely.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).